# Java stream sort map by key and value

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, key, java-stream

There is needed to sort words in a file by amount of entrance a definite symbol (firstly sort by entrance amount then by alphabet). For example, for the symbol 'e' the result should be: avrgspeed=2; became=2; because=2 ... automated=1; autowired=1.

Is there better way to write all in stream-style.

```
             public class Sorter {

public Map<String, Integer> getDistinctWordsMap(String path, char symbol) throws IOException {
    Pattern delimeter = Pattern.compile("([^a-zA-Z])");
    List<WordParameter> parameterList = new ArrayList<>();
    Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
            .flatMap(delimeter::splitAsStream).map(String::toLowerCase).distinct()
            .forEachOrdered(word -> parameterList.add(new WordParameter(word, symbol)));
    Collections.sort(parameterList);
    return parameterList.stream().filter(w->w.count>0).collect(toMap(n->n.word, n->n.count, (e1, e2) -> e1, LinkedHashMap::new));
}

class WordParameter implements Comparable<WordParameter>{
    String word;
    int count;

    public WordParameter(String word, char symbol) {
        this.word = word;
        this.count = countEntrance(symbol);
    }

    private int countEntrance(char symbol){
        int quantity = 0;
        char[] charArr = word.toCharArray();
        for(int i = 0; i<charArr.length; i++){
            if(charArr[i]==symbol){
                quantity++;
            }
        }
        return quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(WordParameter o) {
        if(count<o.count)
            return 1;
        else if(count>o.count)
            return -1;
        else {
            return word.compareTo(o.word);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: return type must be map, set or list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could definitely reduce the boilerplate code and make it more concise.

<del>Not tested the code below but</del> something like this should suffice:

```
 Files.lines(Paths.get(path))
      .flatMap(delimeter::splitAsStream)
      .map(String::toLowerCase)
      .filter(s -> s.indexOf(symbol) >= 0)
      .distinct()
      .map(s -> new SimpleEntry<>(s, s.chars().filter(c -> c == symbol).count()))
      .sorted(Map.Entry.<String,Long>comparingByValue(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                    .thenComparing(Map.Entry::getKey))
      .collect(toMap(SimpleEntry::getKey, e -> e.getValue().intValue(), (l, r) -> l, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

This means you don’t need your custom class anymore as we’re using `SimpleEntry` in the stream pipeline.